# How do I stop the text in my Navigation bar from moving up and down when the window is resized

Tags: html, css, text, navbar

As the title says, the text in my navigation bar moves up and down when the window is resized horizontally.  I've tried and tried but I can't find a solution, I've tried using position, vertical-align, and making my logo banner along with the links a percentage height (but that always leaves me with a massive banner no-matter what and the links are actually at the height specified. How do I fix that as well?) I have attached my HTML and CSS for reference.  Do note that I also can't figure out how to get rid of menu-container without screwing everything up.  It would be great if someone could also outline what I have here that is completely unnecessary.  I'm sorry for asking this much, I'm new to this and have been following various tutorials the best I can.  idk if it matter but the dimensions of the image "goatrockbanner.png" are 2000pxx467px.  The height that works best for me on my desktop seems to be about 60px.  Help is greatly appreciated.

```
   <div class='menu-container'>
     <div class='menu'>
       <img class='logobanner' src='files/images/goatrockbanner.png'/>
       <div class='links'>
         <a href='games.html' class="button">Games</a>
         <a href='news.html' class="button">News</a>
         <a href='#forums' class="button">Forums</a>
         <a href='contact.html' class="button">Contact Us</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

```
.menu-container {
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  font-size: 140%;
}

.logobanner {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.links {
  width: 87.5%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.button {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #efefef;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.8%;
  padding-bottom: 0.8%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 140%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.button:hover {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  color: #efefef;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `padding` issue on `.button` element using `%` value. If you are new in CSS you have to read about `units` in CSS and the `%` I would say is the most troublesome as it uses the parent for its calculations. Try to use px and see if it fixes the issue. More about [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)